# Why this customTheme is not applied to my buttons

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

> Why this customTheme is not applied to my buttons. I'm using the MUI 5. Please tell me where I'm making the mistakes & how to resolve this.

```
import React from 'react';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';

const customTheme = createTheme({
overrides: {
   MuiButton: {
     outlined: {
        backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(to top, #d299c2 0%, #fef9d7 100%)',
        color: 'green'
      },
      text: {
        color: "red"
      }
    }
  }
})

function App() {
  return (
    <div id='appDiv2'>
      <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
        <NavBar />
        <Button variant='outlined'> Test Button </Button>
      </ThemeProvider>
      <DirectionSnackbar />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please format your question properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of the theme object depends on the version of MaterialUI. If you use latest, the scheme should be

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    // Name of the component
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        // Name of the slot
        outlined: {
         backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(to top, #d299c2 0%, #fef9d7 100%)',
         color: 'green'
        },
        text: {
         color: "red"
        }
      },
    },
  },
});
```

https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/#global-style-overrides